# How can I fix this overflowing parbox issue?

Tags: margins, indentation, parbox

I am trying to use an indented parbox, but the `\textwidth` command in the width parameter doesn't account for the indentation, and so the text overflows outside of my margin.  How could I fix this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\makebox[2cm][l]{Hello}
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}{\blindtext}
```

to reduce the size of the `\parbox`.

### Notes:

- I also added a trailing `%` to eliminate the space that gets added after the `\makebox`.
- The `showframe` package was used to show the margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\makebox[2cm][l]{Hello}% <--- Trailing % added
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect - nice and easy solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a `\parbox` I suggest a `\leftskip` based environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,showframe}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newenvironment{shiftright}[1]
 {%
  \par
  \setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}\ignorespaces
 }
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{shiftright}{Hello}
\blindtext
\end{shiftright}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, a `list` based environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,showframe}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newenvironment{shiftright}[1]
 {%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2cm}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
  }%
  \item\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}\ignorespaces
 }
 {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{shiftright}{Hello}
\blindtext
\end{shiftright}

\end{document}
```

[image]